# How to implement i18n / translations for ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am internationalizing my app, and after having translated the interface with the yml locale files, I now want to localize my models. I am using ActiveAdmin so the editors can update content and I would like the solution to be suitable for this.

Is there any way to define some of my model attributes as translatable, so rails generates a migration that creates an extra field for each locale / language? This, or something similar, would be my prefered solution, but I a open to other aproaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/rails-i18n/browse_thread/thread/2eaf2303b8fead05?pli=1) you'll find an approach for the same problem you have.

Comment: I ended up using globalize3, following the advice in this thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) gem. It's great gem to manage model translations.